# Problem with removing page number in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

How can I number the initial slides in beamer, while leaving the very last one unnumbered? I tried specifying that I want the last slide's style to be plain and thus without numbering. However, the page number of this last slide still appears, just shifted downwards. What's the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{\insertframenumber}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This slide is numbered, as it should be.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        This slide is also numbered, but I don't want it to be.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you're trying to obtain is the `empty` page style, no the plain one.

Comment: @Bernard This leads to the same problem.

Comment: `\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{}` makes the number disappear.

Comment: @SimonDispa What if I want the first slides to be numbered, but the last one not?

Comment: Please expand you code to multiple slides an explain in your question how you want them numbered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% add only the frame number
%   \hfill%
%   \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]%
%   \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip3pt%
%}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]% frame number /total frames

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        This slide 1 is numbered, as it should be.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    %   \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} % OPTIONAL start next frame with #2
        This slide 2 is also numbered, but I don't want it to be.
        
        (Not anymore)   
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        This slide 3 is numbered, as it should be.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]    
        This slide 4 is the last one and it is also not numbered.
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

[image: c]

Frames are numbered as frame number /total number of frames.

If you want only the frame number replace

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

by

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% add only the frame number
        \hfill%
        \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]%
        \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip3pt%
    }
```

If you want the third slide start with the number 2 instead of 3 add to the second frame

```
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.